# PPTX Package not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I've installed the pptx package using the following command:
`pip install python-pptx`

However, When ever I try to import the package this is the output I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/divyabahri/Documents/hello.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pptx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx
```

Can someone please guide me regarding the latter issues, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you edit the question with `pip -V`, `python -V`, and the command to run the python script included?

Comment: from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

prs.save('test.pptx')

Comment: what python version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Mismatch in the python version could be the cause of the error. The problem can be fixed by explicitly using PIP version 3 and also Python version 3.

**Working demo:**

**Step 1:**  Install python-pptx and its dependencies using pip version 3

```
$ pip3 install python-pptx
$ pip3 install lxml           ---> dependency
$ pip3 install pillow         ---> dependency
```

**Step 2:**  Python 3 program to create a pptx file

```
# File name:  demo.py

from pptx import Presentation 
prs = Presentation() 
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0] 
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout) 
title = slide.shapes.title 
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1] 
title.text = "Hello, World!" 
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!" 
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

**Step 3:**  Execute the program using Python version 3

```
$ python3 demo.py
```

**Step 4:** Verify that the test.pptx file got created.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for that:

1.- Python pptx only supports python version 3.6 or less here is the documentation https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html

2.- Check also your path, check if python version that is availabel for pptx is on the path, here you can see how to check your path, https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-see-names-and-values-of-environment-variables-in-windows-10/

3.- pip is outdated, try to upgrade your pip

4.- maybe you import bad the library, here you can see how to import it, https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

Comment: Note that `python-pptx` is only _tested_ with up to Python 3.6, but there are no known incompatibilities with later versions of Python. There's definitely nothing that hides the module based on the Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code through any IDE may sometime cause this error.
Happened with me when I tried to run through VScode. Try running it through python IDE or cmd just to check for, if opens you can sort out the editor issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34039163)