# Resolving Python-pptx package not found

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to do something fairly simple: store each text box in a powerpoint file as an element in a giant python list. This code should be getting me to that outcome:

```
text_array = []
for eachfile in glob.glob("master_folder\*.pptx"):
    prs = Presentation(eachfile)
    #print(eachfile)
    #print("----------------------")
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if hasattr(shape, "text"):
                text_array.append(shape.text)
```

However, like some other questions on SO ([PPTX Package not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347286/pptx-package-not-found)), I am greeted with the error:

> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at
> 'master_folder\April_2020.pptx'

What I've tried:

- double checking my versions/dependencies: all seems to be in
  order/compatible
- removing all spaces from the files and directories

However, the error has persisted.

### Question

Can someone with experience using this library point me in the right direction for the simple task of scraping in-document text and storing it within an native python list (as seen in my code)?

Comment: Haven't used the library myself, but this [GH issue](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/625#issuecomment-877369853) seems to have the answer you are looking for. The error is not saying it can't find the python library like the other issue you linked, but rather is saying it can't find the file you are providing in your forloop OR the file is not actually of a zip. I'd recommend using an absolute file path instead of a relative one when first trying to get it to work.

Comment: Can you open that file manually? Or is it corrupt? `pptx` is a ZIP package containing XML files in a well known format. It's the same with `docx` and `xlsx`. The error is saying that the *ZIP package* can't be found. It's not a matter of spaces in the file path as you got that path from `glob`. It could also be a very unusual permission issue - you have permissions to list the contents of the folder but not read individual files. While possible, that's highly unusual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- file does not exist
- file is no valid pptx (unzip file and check folder and file structure)
- file is corrupt (opening in MS Office, change, save may fix)
- no access rights for python
- file is locked, e.g. opened by MS Office

if you can't find anything maybe provide a sample pptx which is not working.

Comment: This was kind of the case, had encryption running